# How do I make a query to my index that includes a hierarchical facet programmatically?

Tags: search

I need to make a query that includes a hierarchical facet. I've already managed to make a query that includes facets. What happens is that I have an index with many objects that are related to a hierarchical taxonomy, I need in my query to bring the facet with the hierarchical values so that I don't have to do cycles to add the values of the children and parents. Here I put my code if it helps at all. Thanks in advance

```
$index = Index::load('default_solr_index');
    $query = $index->query();

    $server = $index->getServerInstance();

    if ($server->supportsFeature('search_api_facets')) {
      $query->setOption('search_api_facets', [
        'type' => [
          'field' => 'name_1',
          'limit' => 20,
          'operator' => 'or',
          'min_count' => 1,
          'missing' => TRUE,
        ],
      ]);
    }

    $query->addTag('custom_search');

    $results = $query->execute();
    
    $facets = $results->getExtraData('search_api_facets', []);
```